# Adding an array into an array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Ideally, I'd like the ability to add a 3rd array into an array of 2 arrays.  I've tried array_push, array_merge, and array_merge_recursive. Here is the relevant code:

```
$array1 = array("color" => "red", "shape" => "triangle");
$array2 = array("color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid");
$array3 = array("color" => "blue", "shape" => "square");
$result = array($array1, $array2);
$result = array_merge($result, $array3);
print_r($result);
```

This current code returns: Array ( [0] => Array ( [color] => red [shape] => triangle ) [1] => Array ( [color] => green [shape] => trapezoid ) [color] => blue [shape] => square )

The problem with it is I need it to number the 3rd array as well.  So, [0], [1], and [2]

Comment: What's wrong with this? Your sample code works. `array_push($result, $array3)` also works.

Comment: I don't get the number for the 3rd array

Comment: for($i=0; $i<sizeof($result); $i++){
  print_r($result[$i]); echo '<hr>';
 }

Comment: You just want to add array3? `$result[] = $array3;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array1 = array("color" => "red", "shape" => "triangle");
$array2 = array("color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid");
$array3 = array("color" => "blue", "shape" => "square");

$result = array($array1, $array2);

array_push($result, $array3);
```

`array_push` is the way to go because you will add the new array to the array of arrays. The issue with `array_merge` is that it takes the contents of `$array3` (not the array itself) and adds them to `$result`.

When you said that you previously tried `array_push` I'm guessing that you used it incorrectly like this: `$result = array_push($result, $array3);` which will overwrite the result you're looking for with the length of the created array, rather than the array you're creating.

Answer (score 1):

You're merging an array of strings (`$array3`) with an array of arrays (`$result`).

To achieve the result you want, you should either do

```
$result = array($array1, $array2, $array3);
```

or use `array_push()` instead of `array_merge()`

```
$result = array($array1, $array2);
array_push($result, $array3);
```